# (PHP, Google Chart) Pie Chart using data in the PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm new to PHP, I tried to create the pie chart on my PHP page but it shows nothing.

These are my codes (I put all codes in HTML section)

-> https://jsfiddle.net/1a4819vz/1/

and this the piechart.php parts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Position', 'Applicant(s)'],

      <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < $table_counter; $i++){
      ?> 

      [<?=$pos_chart[$i]?>, <?=$tapp_chart[$i]?>],

      <?php 
        }
      ?>

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Pie chart of Total Applicants'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

The result for pie chart turns out only the big whole white space like this.

[image]

I don't know why. Please help.

Comment: Show us how looks generated js code.

Comment: @nospor image updated

Comment: I asked for generated js code not image. You dynamically generate js code (some chart arrays) - I am asking for this.

Comment: I can see he is using google.visualization.PieChart library. Thus, this whole question is about how he misused the google library.

Comment: @David162795 yeah, I have no idea about what I have to do now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array values aren't being printed to JavaScript

need to use something like

`<?=$pos_chart[$i]?>`

or

`<?php echo $tapp_chart[$i]?>`

and don't see the need for the `if` statement

try this...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Position', 'Applicant(s)'],

  <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $table_counter; $i++){
  ?>

  [<?="'".$pos_chart[$i]."'"?>,   <?=$tapp_chart[$i]?>],

  <?php
    }
  ?>

]);
```